# My index page is loading slowly. How do I reduce load time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've written a simple rails app that allows users to read and share articles. The index page takes quite some time to load (15+ seconds). The app uses active storage to store images. You can see the relevant logic in the snips below:

Article Model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :votes
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :text, presence: true
  scope :news, -> { where(category: 'news') }
  scope :business, -> { where(category: 'business') }
  scope :ent, -> { where(category: 'entertainment') }
  scope :tech, -> { where(category: 'tech') }
  scope :sports, -> { where(category: 'sports') }
  scope :op, -> { where(category: 'opinion') }
end
```

Article Controller:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all.with_attached_image
end
```

Index View:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="main" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.last.image)) %>)">
  <div class="top-article" >
    <h2><%= @articles.last.title %></h2>
    <p><%= link_to "Read more..." %></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sports" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.sports.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "Sports", sports_path %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="tech" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.tech.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "Technology", tech_path %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="opinion" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.op.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "Opinion", opinion_path %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="entertainment" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.ent.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "Entertainment", entertainment_path %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="business" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.business.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "Business", business_path %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="news" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@articles.news.last.image)) %>)">
    <h2><%= link_to "News", news_path %></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Server log when the index page loads:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:27:49 -0400
   (104.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Rendering articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Article Load (149.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (102.9ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (33.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
  CACHE Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "sports"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 6]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "tech"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:11
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 5]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:11
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 4]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:11
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "opinion"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:14
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:14
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 6]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:14
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "entertainment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:17
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 4]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:17
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 3]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:17
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "business"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:20
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 3]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:20
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:20
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "news"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:23
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:23
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:23
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1568.4ms | Allocations: 49895)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 19.8ms | Allocations: 582)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 16.5ms | Allocations: 84)
Completed 200 OK in 3424ms (Views: 2653.2ms | ActiveRecord: 455.7ms | Allocations: 65918)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9f55aa517ef06efb400772224b2ed1ad79fcdc67/national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:27:59 -0400
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6886238f7fdfe7b65d4b612dbce8e767e88f3624/sp.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:02 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9f55aa517ef06efb400772224b2ed1ad79fcdc67", "filename"=>"national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash"}
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fa5b18519810daf31d7097e6dc74eb7ec9607911/op.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:02 -0400
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--047030fb0bd8c1030a39a28c696411b61be3a8dc/te.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:02 -0400
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f1f125e292037967cb5255b63a84839da9f3b280/ent.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:02 -0400
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Disk Storage (1631.0ms) Generated URL for file at key: gt9sqfytys98anvpa736qe55ib5q (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_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--e66658d231f2906e19dd510a055afc09ef894546/national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_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--e66658d231f2906e19dd510a055afc09ef894546/national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 1642ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 185017)


Started GET "/rails/active_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--e66658d231f2906e19dd510a055afc09ef894546/national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:04 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"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--e66658d231f2906e19dd510a055afc09ef894546", "filename"=>"national-cancer-institute-gyGyIEeikSw-unsplash"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 446)


Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--6886238f7fdfe7b65d4b612dbce8e767e88f3624", "filename"=>"sp"}
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDUT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--047030fb0bd8c1030a39a28c696411b61be3a8dc", "filename"=>"te"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (17.7ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Disk Storage (0.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: g2ke90st65tcfuhjieyucs2tre09 (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhaekpyWlRrd2MzUTJOWFJqWm5Wb2FtbGxlWFZqY3pKMGNtVXdPUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5Od0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYzNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA0Ljk5NVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--c41100ca601a8bc409e555e7a5434206a3c308b6/sp.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22sp.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27sp.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhaekpyWlRrd2MzUTJOWFJqWm5Wb2FtbGxlWFZqY3pKMGNtVXdPUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5Od0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYzNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA0Ljk5NVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--c41100ca601a8bc409e555e7a5434206a3c308b6/sp.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22sp.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27sp.jpg
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fa5b18519810daf31d7097e6dc74eb7ec9607911", "filename"=>"op"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (6.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 302 Found in 105ms (ActiveRecord: 18.0ms | Allocations: 8147)


Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Disk Storage (0.9ms) Generated URL for file at key: xa40a03mddiw90t5g0zgcu3hlezc (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhlR0UwTUdFd00yMWtaR2wzT1RCME5XY3dlbWRqZFROb2JHVjZZd1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5SbExtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuZEdVdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAwNVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--02b924846cb3a78119fce46d0cc6b8e79d028559/te.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22te.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27te.jpg)
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f1f125e292037967cb5255b63a84839da9f3b280", "filename"=>"ent"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhlR0UwTUdFd00yMWtaR2wzT1RCME5XY3dlbWRqZFROb2JHVjZZd1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5SbExtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuZEdVdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAwNVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--02b924846cb3a78119fce46d0cc6b8e79d028559/te.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22te.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27te.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 13.0ms | Allocations: 8653)


  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Disk Storage (0.7ms) Generated URL for file at key: u2ibz9joa1bggou2g0dv5uc6itpy (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkVEpwWW5vNWFtOWhNV0puWjI5MU1tY3daSFkxZFdNMmFYUndlUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW05d0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYjNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAyMloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--2a52ba2e0974eabcb0333eee93bf86e62aa072bb/op.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22op.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27op.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkVEpwWW5vNWFtOWhNV0puWjI5MU1tY3daSFkxZFdNMmFYUndlUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW05d0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYjNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAyMloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--2a52ba2e0974eabcb0333eee93bf86e62aa072bb/op.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22op.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27op.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 4.9ms | Allocations: 6248)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhaekpyWlRrd2MzUTJOWFJqWm5Wb2FtbGxlWFZqY3pKMGNtVXdPUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5Od0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYzNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA0Ljk5NVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--c41100ca601a8bc409e555e7a5434206a3c308b6/sp.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22sp.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27sp.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:05 -0400
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhlR0UwTUdFd00yMWtaR2wzT1RCME5XY3dlbWRqZFROb2JHVjZZd1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5SbExtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuZEdVdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAwNVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--02b924846cb3a78119fce46d0cc6b8e79d028559/te.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22te.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27te.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:05 -0400
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkVEpwWW5vNWFtOWhNV0puWjI5MU1tY3daSFkxZFdNMmFYUndlUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW05d0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYjNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAyMloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--2a52ba2e0974eabcb0333eee93bf86e62aa072bb/op.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22op.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27op.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:05 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"sp.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''sp.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhaekpyWlRrd2MzUTJOWFJqWm5Wb2FtbGxlWFZqY3pKMGNtVXdPUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5Od0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYzNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA0Ljk5NVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--c41100ca601a8bc409e555e7a5434206a3c308b6", "filename"=>"sp"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 419)


Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"te.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''te.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhlR0UwTUdFd00yMWtaR2wzT1RCME5XY3dlbWRqZFROb2JHVjZZd1k2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW5SbExtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuZEdVdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAwNVoiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--02b924846cb3a78119fce46d0cc6b8e79d028559", "filename"=>"te"}
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"op.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''op.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhkVEpwWW5vNWFtOWhNV0puWjI5MU1tY3daSFkxZFdNMmFYUndlUVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpTjJsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW05d0xtcHdaeUk3SUdacGJHVnVZVzFsS2oxVlZFWXRPQ2NuYjNBdWFuQm5CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lQYVcxaFoyVXZhbkJsWndZN0JsUT0iLCJleHAiOiIyMDIwLTA2LTE3VDAzOjMzOjA1LjAyMloiLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2tleSJ9fQ==--2a52ba2e0974eabcb0333eee93bf86e62aa072bb", "filename"=>"op"}
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 385)


Completed 200 OK in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 720)


  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (16.7ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Disk Storage (0.8ms) Generated URL for file at key: io5qey217t7eumab7ly2dw81y9cd (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhVzgxY1dWNU1qRTNkRGRsZFcxaFlqZHNlVEprZHpneGVUbGpaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1WdWRDNXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJWdWRDNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNS4wNjJaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--f265e894e1b5b0f8d7ab481c2c9a13058bba98c5/ent.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22ent.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27ent.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhVzgxY1dWNU1qRTNkRGRsZFcxaFlqZHNlVEprZHpneGVUbGpaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1WdWRDNXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJWdWRDNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNS4wNjJaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--f265e894e1b5b0f8d7ab481c2c9a13058bba98c5/ent.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22ent.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27ent.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 55ms (ActiveRecord: 42.7ms | Allocations: 11728)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhVzgxY1dWNU1qRTNkRGRsZFcxaFlqZHNlVEprZHpneGVUbGpaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1WdWRDNXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJWdWRDNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNS4wNjJaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--f265e894e1b5b0f8d7ab481c2c9a13058bba98c5/ent.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22ent.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27ent.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:05 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"ent.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''ent.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhhVzgxY1dWNU1qRTNkRGRsZFcxaFlqZHNlVEprZHpneGVUbGpaQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1WdWRDNXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJWdWRDNXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNS4wNjJaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--f265e894e1b5b0f8d7ab481c2c9a13058bba98c5", "filename"=>"ent"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 381)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--544bef348f3d127d4acd0aa7ab89130d259f66d7/bus.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:06 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--544bef348f3d127d4acd0aa7ab89130d259f66d7", "filename"=>"bus"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (187.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Disk Storage (19.4ms) Generated URL for file at key: lvy6kstuagdd15xon9wh9mm4usgt (http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhiSFo1Tm10emRIVmhaMlJrTVRWNGIyNDVkMmc1YlcwMGRYTm5kQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1KMWN5NXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJKMWN5NXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNi43MDhaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--3ed8fff7c6cfe9eb65e3f4a2dc12ef4154a6b6c6/bus.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22bus.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27bus.jpg)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhiSFo1Tm10emRIVmhaMlJrTVRWNGIyNDVkMmc1YlcwMGRYTm5kQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1KMWN5NXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJKMWN5NXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNi43MDhaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--3ed8fff7c6cfe9eb65e3f4a2dc12ef4154a6b6c6/bus.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22bus.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27bus.jpg
Completed 302 Found in 270ms (ActiveRecord: 187.2ms | Allocations: 1878)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhiSFo1Tm10emRIVmhaMlJrTVRWNGIyNDVkMmc1YlcwMGRYTm5kQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1KMWN5NXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJKMWN5NXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNi43MDhaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--3ed8fff7c6cfe9eb65e3f4a2dc12ef4154a6b6c6/bus.jpg?content_type=image%2Fjpeg&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22bus.jpg%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27bus.jpg" for ::1 at 2020-06-16 23:28:06 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"content_type"=>"image/jpeg", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"bus.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''bus.jpg", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhiSFo1Tm10emRIVmhaMlJrTVRWNGIyNDVkMmc1YlcwMGRYTm5kQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpT1dsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SW1KMWN5NXFjR2NpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjJKMWN5NXFjR2NHT3daVU9oRmpiMjUwWlc1MFgzUjVjR1ZKSWc5cGJXRm5aUzlxY0dWbkJqc0dWQT09IiwiZXhwIjoiMjAyMC0wNi0xN1QwMzozMzowNi43MDhaIiwicHVyIjoiYmxvYl9rZXkifX0=--3ed8fff7c6cfe9eb65e3f4a2dc12ef4154a6b6c6", "filename"=>"bus"}
Completed 200 OK in 5818ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 405)
```

How can I go about reducing the load-time for this page?

Comment: Are you just running it locally with rails server or is it hosted somewhere? Is this the only page that is slow?

Comment: I'm running it locally for now. I have aws hooked up already to be used in production, although that's currently presenting a separate issue. This is the only page that's loading slowly.

Comment: My only idea is that the url_for routine takes so much time. I would double the url_for routine in the view only to check if the runtime also double. When yes then you have the cause.

Comment: Can you post the log output when you load this page? It will show that your making a GET request on the index action on the Article controller. It will also show timing breakdowns for what I suspect are a lot of DB queries, and then the final load time for the page. If you can post that I can show you what the problem is and how to read the developer log to fix this when you encounter similar situations in the future.

Comment: I’m fairly certain that your use of the scopes in the view is making additional SQL queries and there is a way to make one query in the controller. But that log will show for sure.

Comment: @TomHarvey I think I kinda see what you mean. Some of the images themselves take a long time to load individually. I can at least reduce load time by using smaller image sizes. One thing I do notice, however, is that a number of queries are being made (about 24 or so) when this page attempts to load. Any suggestions on how to reduce this number?

Comment: So when your controller creates `@articles` that’s one query - and it contains the data for when the view calls `@articles.last.image`. But when the view calls `@articles.business.last.image` you require another 1 or 2 DB queries to get the data for that render. Same for sports, tech and other categories. If you paste the output of the terminal we can see the exact queries being made and I’ll be able to suggest a better way; where you make one query in the controller which gets all of the required data in a single call to the DB. Paste that log output into an edit of your original question.

Comment: @TomHarvey I've updated the terminal output. Give it a look whenever you get a chance to.

Answer (score 3):

That rails log is a very very useful but often overlooked thing. It can look like gibberish at first, so let's look through it to see the slowdown; after the `Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML` where it starts to render out your index page.

The first thing it does:

```
Article Load (149.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
```

Shows you the DB query being called (get the last article), how long it takes (149ms) and that it's required because of your code on line 2 of index.html.erb. And, on line 2 you have `@articles.last.image` - this is causing that DB query.

149ms, no big deal ...stick with me here, it's a journey.

The next thing it does is another 2 DB queries, also caused by line 2

```
ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (102.9ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
ActiveStorage::Blob Load (33.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:2
```

This time, it's getting the image resource and that takes another 102ms + 33ms. But, your controller uses `Model.with_attached_image` to preload the image, no? Well, obviously that's not working. Have a look at https://jasoncharnes.com/eager-loading-querying-against-activestorage-attachments/ for a good guide to preloading this.

I think you've got the `.all` in the wrong place. You should be using `Model.with_attached_image.all` instead of `Model.all.with_attached_image`.

But, there's more ...

Next, there are 3 DB queries required by line 4 in the view:

```
CACHE Article Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 8]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
  CACHE ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 7]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:4
```

But, note how these all take 0.0ms and are cached. That's because the previous queries, caused by line 2 have already gotten that data from the DB. Excellent!

Keep an eye out for these kinds of details in the logs while you're developing. Note when the line starts with CACHE, that's good.

You then have 15 uncached DB queries caused by lines 8, 11, 14, 17 and 20 where you're using the category scopes to get data, without any preloading of the image data (`@articles.business.last.image`). So, each scope call makes 3 DB queries.

```
Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."category" = $1 ORDER BY "articles"."id" DESC LIMIT $2  [["category", "sports"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8

  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $3  [["record_type", "Article"], ["name", "image"], ["record_id", 6]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8

  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]
  ↳ app/views/articles/index.html.erb:8
```

Hopefully this has shown you how to spot where the time goes in your logs.

To start to fix it, start small. Make one call to get the last article data and image

controller

```
@latest_article = Articles.with_attached_image.last
```

view

```
<div class="main" style="background-image: url(<%= (url_for(@latest_article.image)) %>)">
  <div class="top-article" >
    <h2><%= @latest_article.title %></h2>
    <p><%= link_to "Read more..." %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That should get the 3 DB queries for line 2 and 4 down to 1 query. Check the log and see how it's changed.

Next are the scoped queries.

You could create explicit calls to each category in the controller, prefetching the image data in each:

```
@tech_article = Article.with_attached_image.where(category: 'tech').last
@news_article = Article.with_attached_image.where(category: 'news').last
# and so on...
```

That way you'll have one DB call per category - a lot fewer than 15

But I note that you're only showing the image for these, not the title. Is that just for brevity o the post here?

Ideally, you want to get this all down to only 1 DB query; but that's going to require a nested SQL query; which might even warrant its own question.

#### Notes on production deployment

In production, all of the GET calls to the images will load a lot faster than they do in your dev environment. Maybe get it online onto a hidden page so you can see how it performs in production - once you get the DB queries down to just 1 or 2

In development you’re serving everything from a single server thread; so everything happens one after the other. On production, the requests for the images (all of the GET requests in your log other than the first GET request for the index) will be made concurrently. This will have a huge impact on that 15s load time you’re seeing.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/… for some SQL on how to request the last item from each category in a single query. How to do that in rails is probably worthy of its own question; this one is a broad “how can I make things faster” question

Comment: What does the log look like now, after the individual category series?

Comment: NB - I edited to add some stress to the note at the end. I wasn’t properly conveying the impact of a production server on the serving of the images.