# Rails Index Page Slow Loading for Large Dataset

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an app with a very large legacy database.  The model I'm currently indexing has 7,075 `stories`.  I'm trying to create a javascript-y way for a user to search through all the records and have them automatically filter asynchronously.

Ideally, here's the blurb (currently a partial in `stories/_blurb` that's being rendered in a `Story.all.each do` block):

```
<div class="pb-4">
    <div id="blurb<%= story.id %>" class="blurb box p-3">
        <div class="text-end">
            <%= render partial: "stories/badges", locals: { story: story, show_author: false } %>
        </div>
        
        <h3 class="header-font mb-0"><%= link_to story.title, story_path(story) %></h3>
        <p class="mb-2 italics">
            <% if story.author %>
                by <%= link_to story.author.penname, author_path(story.author) %>
            <% else %>
                by Unknown Author
            <% end %>
        </p>


        <p><%= simple_format(story.summary) %></p>

        <p class="text-end mt-1 italics small">
            <%= pluralize(story.word_count, "Words") %>,&nbsp;

            <% if story.chapters.count != 0 %>
                Started <%= story.chapters.first.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>,&nbsp;
            <% else %>
                Started <%= story.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>,&nbsp;
            <% end %>

            <% if story.chapters.count != 0 %>
                Updated <%= story.chapters.last.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>
            <% else %>
                Updated <%= story.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %>,&nbsp;
            <% end %>   
        </p>

        <% if @current_author == story.author %>
            <div class="text-end">
                <%= link_to "Edit Story", edit_story_path(story), class: "btn btn-admin btn-small" %>
                <%= button_to "Delete Story", story_path(story), form: { data: { turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this story? This action cannot be undone.' } }, class: "btn btn-small btn-admin", :method => :delete %>
            </div> <!-- author buttons -->
        <% elsif @current_author %>
            <div class="text-start">
                <%= render partial: "story_markers/buttons_read_later", locals: { story: story } %>
                <%= render partial: "story_markers/buttons_read", locals: { story: story } %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div> <!-- story blurb -->
</div>
```

I currently have it working using [Datatables.js](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) in a kind of hacky way (having no header and rendering the above blurb in a single-cell row) that prohibits me from using the AJAX functionality for server-side processing, which means that it takes a literal minute or two to load all 7,075 stories.  After that the search/filter works like a charm, but ain't nobody got time for that....

I have had similar loading time issues for other large datasets on this app as well (there are over 70,000 users) and pagination can only do so much when you need to be able to search.

Is there a way to speed up page loading for an index of a large dataset?  I've looked at posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417337/my-index-page-is-loading-slowly-how-do-i-reduce-load-time) and have an API that gives a JSON of the data...but I haven't found a way to plug it in that actually accomplishes my goals.

Here's what I need:

1. For the index page to load in a reasonable amount of time
2. Some kind of pagination
3. For the user to be able to search all the records by any information (e.g. text in `story.author` and `story.summary` can be searched from the same search bar

If possible, it would be great if the above could be done asynchronously. Some tools I have seen do the thing where your search text is highlighted as you search.  That would be magical, but is definitely on the "wish list" not the "must have" list.

Can anyone see a way to do this in plain Rails or do I need to start looking into Vue or Backbone or something?

Comment: Are you trying to have them search by title or by something like relevancy? Are you using keyword search or are you using filter options? You can AJAX and build the search results dynamically with JS and add something like `Model.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{tag}%"])` to your AJAX-targeted controller action. You could also use templates and render the HTML directly in the request then just loop it into the DOM. Opensearch/Elasticsearch might help a lot with this if you are in need of full-text relevancy search.

Comment: @KevinMaze There is one search field, but they should be able to type in keywords from the`story.title` or from inside the `story.summary` or a penname from `story.author.name`....so it's tricky to write a simple controller method....

Comment: You're most likely going about this wrong - you should always be querying with some sort of pagination or limit if the size of your table is non-trivial. When performing a search you don't pull everything out and then throw the irrevant stuff away - you order the rows by relevance and use limits and paging to get a reasonable amount of rows from the database.

Comment: No matter what indexes you have loading many thousands of model instances in Rails is going to be slow and cause memory issues.

Comment: 7000 is not a large table by any means. But if you try to instantiate all the models, it  will bog down. The search should be done on the server, and use turbo frames to show the responses. It's fast and responsive. The only models you should instantiate are the ones that match the search criteria.

Comment: @Liz I see. I think that using a gem like `pg_search` is more-or-less what you're looking for. This article gives a pretty good overview of how to get full-text search in using the pg_search gem: https://pganalyze.com/blog/full-text-search-ruby-rails-postgres

You can also configure the gem for multisearch, meaning you can have it check multiple columns. If your use-case grows and/or you don't use Postgres, it may end up being worth the tech overhead to check out Opensearch or write raw queries yourself. 

For pagination, the Kaminari gem is great.